# Blackberry Playbook Simulator Closes Immediately

Tags: flash-cs5, blackberry-playbook, sim-card

I have successfully created a .BAR file using Command line syntax, and the same is installed successfully on Simulator, but when I try to start it, it opens up and closes immediately.

I have used following syntax to compile:

```
blackberry-airpackager -package Test.bar -installApp -launchApp Test-app.xml blackberry-tablet.xml Test.swf TicTacToe72.png -device 172.16.217.129
```

I am not using any password on the device, so the allow syntax works fine.

I am using Playbook 1.0 simulator, that comes with BLACKBERRY Adobe AIR SDK.